# Missing prefix in Traefik requests

Tags: docker, traefik

I have some problem when send requests to docker container by Traefik 1.7.16 using PathPrefixStrip
example in docker-compose file

```
service_name:
      container_name: container1
      build: "docker_image/container1"
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.backend=container1
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my.site.net;PathPrefixStrip:/web1
        - traefik.docker.network=web
        - traefik.port=8080
      networks:
        - web
```

When me go to page **my.site.net/web1** application return main page with code 200, but all calls from page like **/somejs.js** looks like **my.site.net/somejs.js** but not like **my.site.net/web1/somejs.js**

Can I solve this problem using only Traefik methods or smth?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use instead:

```
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my.site.net;PathPrefix:/web1
```

From [Traefik 1.7 docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#path-matcher-usage-guidelines):

> Use a *Prefix* matcher if your backend listens on a particular base path but also serves requests on sub-paths. For instance, PathPrefix: /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and /products/shirts. Since the path is forwarded as-is, your backend is expected to listen on /products.

So using `PathPrefix` keeps your `/web1` path intact when fowarding the request to the backend, but once you are using `PathPrefixStrip` as the names says it will strip the path before it forwards the request to the backend, as you can read in the [Traefik 1.7 docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#path-matcher-usage-guidelines):

> Use a *Strip matcher if your backend listens on the root path (/) but should be routeable on a specific prefix. For instance, PathPrefixStrip: /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and /products/shirts.
> Since the path is stripped prior to forwarding, your backend is expected to listen on /.
> If your backend is serving assets (e.g., images or Javascript files), chances are it must return properly constructed relative URLs.
> Continuing on the example, the backend should return /products/shoes/image.png (and not /images.png which Traefik would likely not be able to associate with the same backend).
> The X-Forwarded-Prefix header (available since Traefik 1.3) can be queried to build such URLs dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But PathPerfix don't add /web1/ in server request in sub-paths. Moreover if using PathPrefixStrip and I add web1 in request manually me get resourse body like js or css code, but if me uses PathPrefix in that case me don't get the resourse with code 502

Comment: `But PathPerfix don't add /web1/ in server request in sub-paths.` What I copy pasted from docs doesn't say it add, says it will not remove it from your url. So if you hit Traefik with  `example.com/web1/something`, then the backend will see `/web1/something`, but if you use `PathPrefixStrip` then your backend will just see `/something`. If when using `PathPrefix` your assets are not loading when you visit a page like `example.com/web1/something` then you may have a issue in how you build the urls for them in the backend code.

Comment: My question is: how to get to all requests (seeng in network for example) from page like **my.site.net/web1/somejs.js** instead of  **my.site.net/somejs.js** if index file contains link href="somejs.js"

Comment: So if understand you correctly you are looking to add a prefix not to strip it, and that is not supported in Traefik 1.7, but it's supported in Traefik 2.* https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/addprefix/